# is it safe to pass object of same class, as parameter, to a method of same class in java

Tags: java

I am starting to learn Java and was wondering if I it's normal/safe to pass an object of same class as a parameter to a method in the same class? I tried it and it works, just wanted to know if it's a standard practice.

code snippet below;

```
class App{

    private int databaseFlag=0;
    private String s;
    public App() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        s = "value";
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    App app = new App();

    app.init(app);

    app.methodOne();

    app.methodTwo();
    }

public void init(App app){ 

    DatabaseClass dbc = new DatabaseClass();

    app.databaseFlag = dbc.callDatabaseMethodAndGetFlag(s);
}

public void methodOne(){
    // do something with databaseFlag

}

public void methodTwo(){
    // do something more then reset databaseFlag=0;
}

}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with doing this per se, aside from the fact you could just invoke `app.methodOne()` directly (or `app.init(/* no arg */)`). You have to ask yourself what it would mean to invoke `app.init(someOtherAppInstance)`.

Comment: `app.init(app)` is a bit odd looking, because you're essentially passing `app` twice to the same method (once as an explicit argument and once as `this`). I'm not sure why you think it's necessary.

Comment: This sort of thing is normal, although a little weird in this specific case.  (Normal would be something like `MyClass.equals( MyClass c )`.)  I think you should post more of your code (what are you actually trying to do?) and let us comment on your specific case.  Andy is likely right, what you probably should do is just call `methodOne()` on your own instance directly.

Comment: Made changes to the code for more clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though, with in object's method, you can call other method by its name i.e.,

```
class App {
        private void init () {
            //some code
            someOtherMethod();
        }

        private void someOtherMethod() {
            //someother code
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            App a = new App();
            a.init()
        }
    }
```

See how `someOtherMethod` is being called from `init`? You don't need your class reference here.

To answer your specific question, In Java, every object has access to its reference and that is called `this`, you don't need to pass in the app object. if you absolutely have to refer the object variables, you can do it by this

```
class App{

    private int databaseFlag=0;
    private String s;
    public App() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        s = "value";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.init();
        app.methodOne();
        app.methodTwo();
    }

    public void init(){ 

        DatabaseClass dbc = new DatabaseClass();

        this.databaseFlag = dbc.callDatabaseMethodAndGetFlag(s);
    }

    public void methodOne(){
        // do something with databaseFlag

    }

    public void methodTwo(){
        // do something more then reset databaseFlag=0;
    }
}
```